# Perl's Date::Manip - how to convert a given date into another timezone

Tags: perl, date, timezone

Consider the following code snippet that takes user input (a date) and format it using UnixDate from Date::Manip

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Date::Manip;

my $input = join(" ", @ARGV);
my $date = UnixDate($input, "%Y-%m-%d %T"); 
print $date;
```

This was done to allow users to enter friendly dates such as "*yesterday*" or "*1 week ago*".

I would like to use **$date** with a different timezone (it will be used to extract SQL data). How would this be done?
I did not find any construct of [UnixDate](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.21/lib/Date/Manip/DM6.pod) that would allow to put a timezone, and I do not know either how to reformat the user input (concatenating the name of the timezone to it doesn't help).

**Example**

The user is somewhere in Central Europe (timezone: CET) and enters "today at 1pm". Execution of the code above is as follows:

```
$ ./test.pl today at 1pm
2011-03-03 13:00:00
```

This is the expected result as no timezone change are in effect. What I would like is to use that **$date** with another timezone, e.g. Pacific Standard (timezone: PST). In this case the output should be:

```
$ ./test.pl today at 1pm
2011-03-03 04:00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the  `Date_ConvTZ()` function:

```
 my $date = UnixDate( Date_ConvTZ( $input, 'CET', 'PST' ), "%Y-%m-%d %T");
```

From the manual from [Date::Manip::DM6](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aManip%3a%3aDM6)

Comment: Yes! Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. And there it was, right on the Date::Manip page...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip/) understand timezones but this would be pretty straight forward with [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/):

```
my $input = join(" ", @ARGV);
my $date  = UnixDate($input, "%Y-%m-%d %T");
$date =~ /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/;
my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year      => $1,
    month     => $2,
    day       => $3,
    hour      => $4,
    minute    => $5,
    second    => $6,
    time_zone => 'CET',
);
$dt->set_time_zone('America/Vancouver'); # My DateTime::TimeZone doesn't have PST
```

You might be able to replace your `Date::Manip` uses with one or more of the [DateTime modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime&mode=module) too, `DateTime` is the standard date manipulation library for Perl so using it for all your date-time needs makes sense; OTOH, use what works for you and there's probably no harm in using both `Date::Manip` and `DateTime` if that gets the job done.