# Perl convert timezone gives erroneous output

Tags: perl, timezone, timezone-offset

Trying to convert a given time from one timezone to another based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178248/perls-datemanip-how-to-convert-a-given-date-into-another-timezone).
But the output is erroneous. tried different values but no luck.
any help on whats missing?

```
use Date::Manip::DM6;
use DateTime::Format::DateManip;

my $date2 = '2015-03-24 06:00:00';
$date1 = DateTime::Format::DateManip->parse_datetime( $date2);

my $newdate= UnixDate(Date_ConvTZ($date1 , 'EST', 'PST' ),"%Y-%m-%d %T");
print "date is $date1 and newdate is $newdate";
```

> E:>perl test.pl
>
> date is 2015-03-24T06:00:00 and newdate is 2015-03-23 12:00:00

Expected result is newdate=> 2015-03-24 03:00:00

Comment: What time zones do you think EST and AST are?  Many time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

There are [two ESTs and two ASTs and two PSTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) and like five CSTs.

```
AST     Arabia Standard Time                    UTC+03
AST     Atlantic Standard Time                  UTC−04

EST     Eastern Standard Time (North America)   UTC−05
EST     Eastern Standard Time (Australia)       UTC+10

PST     Pacific Standard Time (North America)   UTC−08
PST     Philippine Standard Time                UTC+08
```

In general, avoid using time zone abbreviations because they are ambiguous.  Use offsets instead.

I get your expected result when I run your code without DateTime::Format::DateManip (which I can't get to pass tests).

```
use v5.10;
use Date::Manip::DM6;

say UnixDate(
    Date_ConvTZ("2015-03-24 06:00:00", "EST", "PST"),
    "%Y-%m-%d %T"
);
# 2015-03-24 03:00:00
```

But don't gamble on the date library happening to pick the same meaning for a time zone abbreviation as you, just don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using DateTime's [builtin](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.18/lib/DateTime.pm#$dt-%3Eset_time_zone(_$tz_)) to change the time zone of your DateTime object? It uses [Olson DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) time zone names.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the [documentation for Date-Manip's valid time zone formats](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.49/lib/Date/Manip/Date.pod#VALID_TIME_ZONE_FORMATS).  It will accept either a time zone offset (such as `-0500`), a time zone abbreviation (such as `EST`), or an Olson time zone identifier (such as `America/New_York`).  It will also accept a combination of values such as `-0500 (EST)`.

I haven't tried, but I would also think that it would accept a combined Olson identifier with offset.  If so, then that would be the most unambiguous representation.

Keep in mind that an offset is only part of the time zone representation.  Many time zones switch offset for daylight saving time.  If you always use a fixed offset, or an abbreviation, you might be passing EST when actually the Eastern time zone would be following Eastern *Daylight* Time (EDT).